# Jw player error when embed code youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, jwplayer, flash

i need help.
i have a problem with JW Player embed code using youtube
i had tried follow the tutorial on following link:
[How to embed using youtube](http://influxis.com/how-to-embed-the-jw-player/#step4)

and this is my code :

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        flashplayer: 'jwplayer/player.swf',
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdF_nqQy8qQ",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
</body>
```

but when i try my code, video doesn't show and this is the error message show on console chrome :

> GET http://localhost/stc/jwplayer/undefined 404 (Not Found)

please help me.

Comment: Have you tried it live

Comment: And why are you using flash?

Comment: @RachelGallen I 've been watching a youtube video directly. I use flash to make sure I can run video on the flash to video that is already running. if the problem is successfully solved I want to try to use flash for streaming video files.

Comment: but flash is so out of date!! you will note that article was written in 2012!

Comment: The JW Player can be rendered in either Flash or HTML5 mode. If you use the code I provided below, it will work, and render the player in HTML5 mode, with Flash as a fallback for legacy browsers. Try that.

Comment: @RachelGallen because I have a job related to jwplayer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JW Player needs to be at least embedded in a local web server in order to work. I just tested your code and it works fine. Try this sample code on either a local web server or public test page, it works.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdF_nqQy8qQ",
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, and.. i have one more question, would you like to try my code : `<embed allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="undefined" flashvars="file=dewaruci.stream&amp;streamer=rtmp://atcs.baliprov.go.id:1935/liv‌​e&amp;controlbar=none&amp;dock=false&amp;autostart=true&amp;repeat=always" height="248" width="330" id="single2" name="single2" src="jwplayer/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"> </embed>` i want to embed video streaming with JW Player .and i get same error.. please help me..

Comment: You cannot embed the JW Player using <embed> code, it has to be done with JavaScript, just as I posted above.

Comment: Besides not being able to use an <embed> tag, that "player.swf" file is from JW Player 5. It's obsolete. You can't use it with JW Player 6.

Answer (score 0):

To embed this video into html simply use an iframe

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KdF_nqQy8qQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about using JW Player to embed a YouTube video. Telling the user "don't use JW Player" isn't really helpful.